# Facebook-App: Set a FB-cookie/token

Tags: facebook, forms, cookies, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook-App with a form to submit. I only want the users to be able to fill out the form once. What I would like to do is set a cookie + I was wondering if I can set something like a FB App-Cookie/token, that tells Javascript that I can't submit again?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is just a regular iframe, so you can set cookies just as easily as if it were a normal website, outside of Facebook.

Don't forget, though, that you should never trust user input, so you will want to validate against multiple entries on the server as well — either by checking their Facebook user ID or some unique piece of information from your form (like the user's email address, for example).

But yes, you can easily set a cookie from the iframe. You should test to make sure that browsers aren't blocking it as a third-party cookie, though. You can test that easily enough by setting Firefox's preferences to disallow third-party cookies and so on.

Hope this helps!